# JQgrid: control to edit just 1 of 3 fields

Tags: jqgrid, controls

I need a special control for these 3 fields: on submit I should verify that the user has edited just one of them (he has to choose only 'element1' or 'element2 or 'element3').

```
[...]
{name:'element1', editable:true,hidden: true ,editrules: {edithidden:true,number:true}, editoptions:{size:5}, reloadAfterSubmit: true,index:'element1',width:40, reloadAfterSubmit: true,closeAfterAdd:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true},
{name:'element2', editable:true,hidden: true ,editrules: {edithidden:true,number:true}  , editoptions:{size:5},reloadAfterSubmit: true,index:'element2',width:40, reloadAfterSubmit: true,closeAfterAdd:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true}
{name:'element3', editable:true,hidden: true ,editrules: {edithidden:true,number:true}  , editoptions:{size:5},reloadAfterSubmit: true,index:'element3',width:40, reloadAfterSubmit: true,closeAfterAdd:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true}
[...]
```

Maybe 'beforeSubmit' in add/edit options could help me but I can't make it work.
Thanks in advance